# Is this an issue with my PHP Session?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, sessionid

I am using sessions to log users into my site.

The login form sends the input to a login-exec file which then queries the db and validates the login info. I have placed `session_start();` at the beginning of the login-exec file and then used the below snippet to write data to the session:

```
session_regenerate_id();
$member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
$_SESSION['Username'] = $member['username'];
$_SESSION['key'] = $member['Serial'];
session_write_close();
header('Location: account.php');
```

at the beginning of the account.php file i have required the auth.php to validate the session.

account.php: `require_once('auth.php');`

auth.php:

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
    header("Refresh: 5; url=login.php");
    //echo $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
    die("Access Denied!");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Always the first time logging in it returns access denied. When the script redirects back to the login page and I try again it always works... I have saved my php files in UTF-8 Without BOM as I originally thought there was leading white space before the session was started. That did not fix the issue and I really can't figure this out.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: It might have something to the session_write_close(); call.  I'm confused about the order in which these snippets are executed.

Comment: I'd remove the `session_write_close()` call.

Comment: I removed the session_write_close() and same results are occuring. 

The order which the events are firing are as written: Login posts data to login-exec.php which validates and write validated info to session which then login-exec.php forwards the user to account.php. In the account.php I have required auth.php to check to see if the SESS_MEMBER_ID has been set. IT is the auth.php which is throwing the issue the first time but subsequently works anytime after that as long as I don't clear my cache.

Comment: could it be because I am calling session_regenerate_id(); before storing my session variables in login-exec.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue was the redirection url in my login-exec.php script. For example:

If I loaded the login.php script by going to http://www.mydomain.com/mysubdirectory/login.php and the header redirect in login-exec.php was pointing to http://subdomain.mydomain.com/account.php the PHPSESSID was being regenerated because the domain changed.

So I changed the header redirects to account.php instead of the full url and this resolved the issue.

I could have used a full URL either subdomain.mydomain.com or mydomain.com/subdirectory/ but in doing so would of restricted the user and the scripts portability. So simple answer..ensure the domain is staying the same. If it isn't you can set the session name which I am pretty sure would resolve this aswell. However in my case `header('Location: script.php');` did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the session_write_close();

If that doesn't solve it, it might be that you are losing the session in the account.php file.

Make a call to `session_start();` before requiring the auth.php page.

Comment: Done and the results are the same.

Comment: @Drew: Why are you calling session_regenerate_ID() in this script? BTW, that this advice didn't solve the problem is not a reason for -1... it just means there are more issues to be fixed.

Comment: I didnt down vote you...someone else must have. And I have tried removing session_regenerate_ID() and it still doesnt work.

Comment: @Drew Ok. Did you try printing the $_SESSION variable just after setting it, just to make sure that it is properly populated?

Comment: Yes I printed it and it is set. but doesnt transfer through to other pages.

Comment: i looked at the resources in chrome and it seems to be with the sessionid. one is present but after the access denied and it redirects back to login the sessionid changes....and then stays through the login....

Comment: the issue was I was inadvertently changing domains through my header redirection.